# Force uninstall of Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I was developing a website using the ASP.NET platform on Visual Studio 2015 Community with Updates 1. But I tried using design mode and the IDE was so slow! 
I could not do anything else. I've tried to repair, but after 15 hours, nothing happened. So, I've prefered the uninstall, but it wasn't had progress. Is there anything that I can do about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the Revo Uninstaller Software, this looks for registry entries of the Program and removes them to.
Havent used it since a long time, but removing some toolbars without proper uninstallers it did its job just fine. 
Another Tip:
Visual Studio creates a System Recovery Point before you install/uninstall/repair it. Try to restore your PC to that should be the easiest method.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know how to give you the best answer.Thank you :)